# Integration Exercise.Help!

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration, advice

I have to integrate the function **F(x,y)=x+y** on the line segment **x=t** , **y=1-t** , **z=0** from **(0,1,0)** to **(1,0,0)** .So what i did is think the line segment as a vector function(curve) **σ(t)=(t,1-t,0)** with domain **A**:[0,1] kai took the contour integral of **F(σ(t))*||σ'(t)||dt** from [0,1] an found sqr2.Is it right? Would it be wrong to think the integral of **F(x)** as the double integral of **F(x)** as **0<=x<=1**, **0<=y<=1-x** ?? I did both ways found different result so i think the way with the double integral is wrong but dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So u mean if you do it like in your second case i.e
$$\int \int_R{ }F(x,y)dydx $$ where R is the region bounded as 0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1-x.thats taking points from that 2-d region R and evaluating F over these points. Then thats wrong if you were asked to integrate the function F(x,y)=x+y on the line segment.

Comment: Yeah now i understand that i take more points than i have to integrate. because i only need the line segment.